# Data from Api, showing multiple objects without array. should the class be created individually for each object

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine

i have the below data from an api which gives me the below data.

i want to access the individual data under each date and put it into a chart in Unity with c#.

when i checked the examples, i could find examples only involving arrays. but this api throws only as individual objects. now should i create individual classes against individual date? i have nearly 250 dates from which i need the data to be extracted.

```
{
"Meta Data":  {

    "1. Information": "Weekly Adjusted Prices and Volumes",
    "2. Symbol": "MSFT",
    "3. Last Refreshed": "2018-06-13",
    "4. Time Zone": "US/Eastern"
},
"Weekly Adjusted Time Series": {

    "2018-06-13": {
        "1. open": "101.3700",
        "2. high": "102.0100",
        "3. low": "100.5600",
        "4. close": "100.8500",
        "5. adjusted close": "100.8500",
        "6. volume": "70511616",
        "7. dividend amount": "0.0000"
    },

    "2018-06-08": {
        "1. open": "101.2600",
        "2. high": "102.6900",
        "3. low": "100.3800",
        "4. close": "101.6300",
        "5. adjusted close": "101.6300",
        "6. volume": "122316267",
        "7. dividend amount": "0.0000"
    },

    "2018-06-01": {
        "1. open": "97.8400",
        "2. high": "100.8600",
        "3. low": "97.2300",
        "4. close": "100.7900",
        "5. adjusted close": "100.7900",
        "6. volume": "113626024",
        "7. dividend amount": "0.0000"
    },

    "2018-05-25": {
        "1. open": "97.0000",
        "2. high": "98.9800",
        "3. low": "96.3200",
        "4. close": "98.3600",
        "5. adjusted close": "98.3600",
        "6. volume": "101128083",
        "7. dividend amount": "0.0000"
    }
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

ok. First your json is brain hurting. If you can fix it, do it:

- You should not have an index inside your keys.
- `Weekly Adjusted Time Series` should be an array.
- Date should not be a key but should be a value inside the object. Something like this: `{ "date": "2018-05-25", "open": "97.0000", [...] }`

Well **IF** you are not able to fix the json, here is a solution and I am not sure it is a great one. I hope someone else have something better to offer. Here we go:

[Demo online on .NetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/3VeU35)

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Globalization;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Converters;

internal static class Converter
{
    public static readonly JsonSerializerSettings Settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
    {
        MetadataPropertyHandling = MetadataPropertyHandling.Ignore,
        DateParseHandling = DateParseHandling.None,
        Converters = {
            new IsoDateTimeConverter { DateTimeStyles = DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal }
        },
    };
}

public class Welcome
{
    [JsonProperty("Meta Data")]
    public MetaData MetaData { get; set; }

    // we save it for a second deserialize
    [JsonProperty("Weekly Adjusted Time Series")]
    private JObject JWeeklyAdjustedTimeSeries { get; set; }

    // this is the object as it should be
    public IEnumerable<WeeklyAdjustedTime> WeeklyAdjustedTimeSeries { get; set; }

    public static Welcome FromJson(string json)
    {
        // first pass
        var welcome = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Welcome>(json, Converter.Settings);
        // second pass
        welcome.WeeklyAdjustedTimeSeries = welcome.JWeeklyAdjustedTimeSeries.ToObject<Dictionary<string, JObject>>().Select(x => {
            var wat = x.Value.ToObject<WeeklyAdjustedTime>();       
            return new WeeklyAdjustedTime
            {
                Date = x.Key,
                Open = wat.Open,
                High = wat.High,
                Low = wat.Low,
                Close = wat.Close,
                AdjustedClose = wat.AdjustedClose,
                Volume = wat.Volume,
                DividendAmount = wat.DividendAmount
            };
        });
        return welcome;
    }
}

public class MetaData
{
    [JsonProperty("1. Information")]
    public string Information { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("2. Symbol")]
    public string Symbol { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("3. Last Refreshed")]
    public DateTimeOffset LastRefreshed { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("4. Time Zone")]
    public string TimeZone { get; set; }
}

public class WeeklyAdjustedTime
{
    public string Date { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("1. open")]
    public string Open { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("2. high")]
    public string High { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("3. low")]
    public string Low { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("4. close")]
    public string Close { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("5. adjusted close")]
    public string AdjustedClose { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("6. volume")]
    public string Volume { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("7. dividend amount")]
    public string DividendAmount { get; set; }
}
```

How to use it:

```
var welcome = Welcome.FromJson(json); // put your json here
Console.WriteLine(welcome.MetaData.Information);
Console.WriteLine(welcome.WeeklyAdjustedTimeSeries.First().Date);
Console.WriteLine(welcome.WeeklyAdjustedTimeSeries.First().Open);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another post for another answer. A custom `JsonConverter` is a less hacky way to achieve what you want. Once again we are trying to fight the JSON. Lets see:

[Demo on .NetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Tp6UW3)

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Globalization;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Converters;

internal static class Converter
{
    public static readonly JsonSerializerSettings Settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
    {
        MetadataPropertyHandling = MetadataPropertyHandling.Ignore,
        DateParseHandling = DateParseHandling.None,
        Converters = {
            new IsoDateTimeConverter { DateTimeStyles = DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal }
        }
    };
}

public class Welcome
{
    [JsonProperty("Meta Data")]
    public MetaData MetaData { get; set; }

    // Look Ma! No hands!
    [JsonProperty("Weekly Adjusted Time Series")]
    [JsonConverter(typeof(WelcomeConverter))]
    public IEnumerable<WeeklyAdjustedTime> WeeklyAdjustedTimeSeries  { get; set; }
}

public class WelcomeConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return (objectType == typeof(object));
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException("Not implemented yet");
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.Null)
        {
            return Enumerable.Empty<WeeklyAdjustedTime>();
        } 
        // first and only pass!
        return JObject.Load(reader).ToObject<Dictionary<string, JObject>>().Select(x => {
            var wat = x.Value.ToObject<WeeklyAdjustedTime>();       
            return new WeeklyAdjustedTime
            {
                Date = x.Key,
                Open = wat.Open,
                High = wat.High,
                Low = wat.Low,
                Close = wat.Close,
                AdjustedClose = wat.AdjustedClose,
                Volume = wat.Volume,
                DividendAmount = wat.DividendAmount
            };
        });

    }
}


public class MetaData
{
    [JsonProperty("1. Information")]
    public string Information { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("2. Symbol")]
    public string Symbol { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("3. Last Refreshed")]
    public DateTimeOffset LastRefreshed { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("4. Time Zone")]
    public string TimeZone { get; set; }
}

public class WeeklyAdjustedTime
{
    public string Date { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("1. open")]
    public string Open { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("2. high")]
    public string High { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("3. low")]
    public string Low { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("4. close")]
    public string Close { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("5. adjusted close")]
    public string AdjustedClose { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("6. volume")]
    public string Volume { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("7. dividend amount")]
    public string DividendAmount { get; set; }
}
```

How to use it:

```
var welcome = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Welcome>(json, Converter.Settings);  // put your json here
Console.WriteLine(welcome.MetaData.Information);
Console.WriteLine(welcome.WeeklyAdjustedTimeSeries.First().Date);
Console.WriteLine(welcome.WeeklyAdjustedTimeSeries.First().Open);
```

Comment: @aloistg. thank you very much for the support.. the code works great.. I have got what i wanted..

Comment: @Krishna_psk glad to be helpful! Don't forget to mark it as resolved and to upvote. Have a nice time on Stack Overflow 